# Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Tags: php, html, poo

Hola primero que nada entiendo que el error puede ser producido por espacios en blanco antes de `<?php` o después de las etiquetas de cierre. pero la verdad no encuentro el problema en mi código, el mensaje es el siguiente.

> [10-Aug-2017 05:49:15 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/POO/proyecto/Views/template.php:65) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/POO/proyecto/Controllers/EstudiantesController.php on line 47

**template.php**

```html
<?php namespace Views;
$template = new Template();

class Template
{
public function __construct()
{
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>SIS32 | byCODE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Views/template/css/bootstrap-paper.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Views/template/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Views/template/css/myStyle.css">
    <script src="/Views/template/js/jquery.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Administración de estudiantes</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class=""><a href="/">Inicio <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>

                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
                       aria-expanded="false">Estudiantes <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="/estudiantes">Listar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/estudiantes/agregar">Agregar</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
                       aria-expanded="false">Secciones <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="/secciones">Listar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/secciones/agregar">Agregar</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>


            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">byCode</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>


<div class="container" id="container"><?php }

    public function __destruct(){

?></div>
    <script src="/Views/template/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}


}
?>
```

**EstudiantesController.php**

```html
<?php namespace Controllers;

use Models\Estudiante as Estudiantes;
use Models\Seccion as Secciones;

class EstudiantesController
{
    private $estudiante;
    private $section;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->estudiante = new Estudiantes();
        $this->section = new Secciones();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $datos = $this->estudiante->listar();
        return $datos;
    }

    public function editar($id)
    {
        print 'Editar el alumno ' . $id;
    }

    public function agregar()
    {
        if ($_POST) {
            $permitidos = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/jpg');
            $limite = 700;

            if (in_array($_FILES['imagen']['type'], $permitidos) && $_FILES['imagen']['size'] <= $limite * 1024) {
                $nombre = date('is') . $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
                $ruta = 'Views' . DS . 'template' . DS . 'imagenes' . DS . 'avatars' . DS . $nombre;
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'], $ruta);


                try {
                    $this->estudiante->setNombre($_POST['nombre']);
                    $this->estudiante->setEdad($_POST['edad']);
                    $this->estudiante->setPromedio($_POST['promedio']);
                    $this->estudiante->setImagen($nombre);
                    $this->estudiante->setIdseccion($_POST['idseccion']);
                    $this->estudiante->add();
                    header("Location: " . URL . "estudiantes");


                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    echo 'Ah ocurrido un error al registrar el alumno ' . $e->getCode();
                }


            } else {
                print 'imagen no permitida';
            }

        } else {
            $datos = $this->section->listar();
            return $datos;
        }


    }
}
$estudiante = new EstudiantesController();
?>
```

**Nota:** estoy siguiendo un videotutorial de `poo`, a continuación dejo el **template.php** que se muestra en el curso.

```html
<?php namespace Views;
 $template = new Template();
 class Template{
  public function __construct(){
?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="es">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Administración de estudiantes | Codigo Facilito</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo URL; ?>Views/template/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo URL; ?>Views/template/css/general.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
          <span class="sr-only"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo URL; ?>">Administración de Estudiantes</a>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="<?php echo URL; ?>">Inicio</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Estudiantes <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li>Listado</li>
              <li>Agregar</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Secciones <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="<?php echo URL; ?>secciones">Listado</a></li>
              <li><a href="<?php echo URL; ?>secciones/agregar">Agregar</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li>SENA</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
<?php
  }
  public function __destruct(){
?>
 <footer class="navbar-fixed-bottom">
  Todos los derechos reservados &copy 2017 <br>
  Fresley Quiñones Angarita ~ @_bycar | <b>SENA</b>
 </footer>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="<?php echo URL; ?>Views/template/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
<?php
  }
 }
?>
```

Comment: El problema es esta linea: `header("Location: " . URL . "estudiantes");` no puede haber ningún `echo, print, código HTML... etc` antes de ello en cuando llames el método `agregar`

Comment: Buenas, ¿te valió la respuesta? ¿Necesitas más información?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente el problema es que has empezado a mandar contenido al navegador y mientras lo estás haciendo, has intentado modificar las cabeceras de la respuesta.

Evidentemente, esas cabeceras ya están enviadas y no se pueden modificar de nuevo, porque la respuesta ya se ha definido y no se puede cambiar mientras se "envía"

Para no hacer "copiar y pegar" te pongo una URL donde se explica bastante bien el tipo de error y las posibles causas:

http://librosweb.es/foro/pregunta/128/como-solucionar-el-problema-headers-already-sent-de-php/

En tu caso por lo que veo el problema es la linea de `header("Location: " . URL . "estudiantes");`

De todas formas, ¿que tipo de plantillas estas usando? ¿La estas creando tú mismo?

Creo que te solucionaría mucho el trabajo el uso de algún motor de plantillas para `PHP`, algunos ejemplos:

- `Blade`: La usa Laravel por defecto. [Como usar Blade sin Laravel](http://asika.windspeaker.co/post/3975-use-blade-template-engine-outside-laravel)
- `Twig`: La usa Symfony por defecto. [Como usar Twig sin Symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33614604/twig-using-without-symfony)
- `Smarty`: Algunos CMS que he conocido la usan, fue mi primer motor de plantillas. [Como instalar Smarty](https://www.smarty.net/quick_install)