# Problema al crear registros en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo este problema respecto al registro de usuarios , como tal no me esta funcionando el registro de usuarios ya que me lleva a este mensaje, dice que tengo un problema con la URL pero no se que pueda ser , llevo 12 horas mirando cual pueda ser el problema pero la verdad es que no logro identificar porque la sintaxis del codigo esta bien hecha, ¿que puedo hacer? ya he intentado de todo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[[image: ![![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como tal si se ven los registros en la base de datos pero tengo una falla de codigo y no se que sea , deberia salirme una alerto de error que hice en caso de no llenar los campos y si los llena una alerta de regidstro con exito y borrar la sesion de registro.¿Que deberia cambiar?

[[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Como tal  `.base_url.` es la que se conecta con las paginas y se definio en la parte de parametros , La clase save guarda el usuario en la base de datos ,

Estos son mis archivos estoy trabajando con modelo MVC:

```
tienda-php/config/db.php

<?php

class Database{
    public static function connect(){
        $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'tienda_php');
        $db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        return $db;
    }
}
```

```
tienda-php/config/parameters.php

<?php
define("base_url", "http://localhost:8080/tienda-php/");
define("controller_default", "productoController");
define("action_default", "index");
```

```
tienda-php/controllers/UsuarioController.php

<?php
require_once 'models/usuario.php';

class usuarioController{

   public function index(){
       echo "Controlador Usuarios, Accion index";
   }
   
   public function registro() {
       require_once 'views/usuario/registro.php';

   }

   public function save() {
       if(isset($_POST)){

           $nombre = isset($_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre'] : false;
           $apellidos = isset($_POST['apellidos']) ? $_POST['apellidos'] : false;
           $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : false;
           $password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : false;

           if($nombre && $apellidos && $email && $password){
               $usuario = new Usuario();
               $usuario->setNombre($nombre);
               $usuario->setApellidos($apellidos);
               $usuario->setEmail($email);
               $usuario->setPassword($password);

               $save = $usuario->save();
               if($save){
                   $_SESSION['register'] = "complete";
               }else{
                   $_SESSION['register'] = "failed";
               }
           }else{
               $_SESSION['register'] = "failed";
           }
       }else{
           $_SESSION['register'] = "failed";
       }    
       header("Location:".base_url.'usuario/registro');
       }
  
//         public function login(){
//             if(isset($_POST)){
//                 //Identificar al usuario
//                 //Consulta a la base de datos
//                 $usuario = new Usuario();
//                 $usuario->setEmail($_POST['email']);
//                 $usuario->setPassword($_POST['password']);
               
//                 $identity = $usuario->login();

//                 if($identity  && is_object($identity)){
//                     $_SESSION['identity'] = $identity;

//                     if($identity->rol == 'admin'){
//                           $_SESSION['admin'] = true;
//                     }
                
//                 }else{
//                     $_SESSION['error_login'] = 'Identificacion fallida !!';
//                 }

//             }
//             header("Location:".base_url);     
//             ob_end_flush();  
//         }

//         public function logout(){
//            if(isset($_SESSION['identity'])){
//                unset ($_SESSION['identity']);
//            }

//            if(isset($_SESSION['admin'])){
//             unset ($_SESSION['admin']);
//            }

//            header("Location:".base_url);

//         }

}//fin clase
```

```
tienda-php/models/usuario.php

<?php

class Usuario{
    private $id;
    private $nombre;
    private $apellidos;
    private $email;
    private $password;
    private $rol;
    private $imagen;
    private $db;

    public function __construct() {        
        $this->db = Database::connect();
    }

    function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    function getNombre() {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    function getApellidos() {
        return  $this->apellidos;
    }

    function getEmail() {
        return  $this->email;
    }
    
    function getPassword() {
        return password_hash($this->db->real_escape_string($this->password), PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 4]);
    }

    function getRol() {
        return  $this->rol;
    }

    function getImagen() {
        return  $this->imagen;
    }

    function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    function setNombre($nombre) {
        $this->nombre = $this->db->real_escape_string($nombre);
    }

    function setApellidos($apellidos) {
        $this->apellidos = $this->db->real_escape_string($apellidos);
    }

    function setEmail($email) {
        $this->email = $this->db->real_escape_string($email);
    }

    function setPassword($password) {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    function setRol($rol) {
        $this->rol = $rol;
    }

    function setImagen($imagen) {
        $this->imagen = $imagen;
    }


    public function save(){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES(NULL, '{$this->getNombre()}', '{$this->getApellidos()}', '{$this->getEmail()}', '{$this->getPassword()}', 'user', null);";
        $save = $this->db->query($sql);
        
        $result = false;
        if ($save){
            $result = true;
        }
        return $result;
    }

    //    public function login(){
    //       $result = false;
    //       $email = $this->email;
    //       $password = $this->password;


    //       //Comprobar si existe el usuario
    //       $sql = " SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email'";
    //       $login = $this->db->query($sql);

    //       if ($login && $login->num_rows == 1){
    //           $usuario = $login->fetch_object();


    //           //verificar la contrasena
    //           $verify = password_verify($password, $usuario->password);

    //           if ($verify){
    //               $result = $usuario;
    //           }
    //       } 

    //       return $result;
    //     }

}
```

```
tienda-php/views/usuario/registro.php

<div id="register" style="margin-left:4%;">

    <h1>Registrar usuarios</h1>
    
    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['register'])  &&  $_SESSION['register'] == 'complete'): ?>
        <strong class="alerta"> Registro completado correctamente</strong>
    <?php elseif (isset($_SESSION['register']) && $_SESSION['register'] =!'failed'): ?>
        <strong class="alerta-error">Falla en el registro, escriba bien los datos</strong>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php Utils::deleteSession('register'); ?>

    <form action="<?=base_url?>usuario/save" method="post">
        <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" requiredrequired />

        <label for="apellidos">Apellidos</label>
        <input type="text" name="apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos" required />

        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" required />

        <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" required />

        <input type="submit" value="Registrarse" />
    </form>
   
</div>
```

```
tienda-php/index.php

<?php
session_start();
require_once 'autoloap.php';
require_once 'config/db.php';
require_once 'config/parameters.php';
require_once 'helpers/utils.php';
require_once 'views/layout/header.php';
require_once 'views/layout/sidebar.php';

function show_error(){
    $error = new errorController();
    $error->index();
}

if (isset($_GET['controller'])) {
    $nombre_controlador = $_GET['controller'].'Controller';

}elseif(!isset($_GET['controller']) && !isset($_GET['action'])){
    $nombre_controlador = controller_default;

} else {
    show_error();
    exit();
}

if (class_exists($nombre_controlador)) {
    $controlador = new $nombre_controlador();

    if(isset($_GET['action']) && method_exists($controlador, $_GET['action'])){
        $action = $_GET['action'];
        $controlador->$action();   
    }elseif(!isset($_GET['controller']) && !isset($_GET['action'])){
        $action_default = action_default;
        $controlador->$action_default(); 
    } else {
        show_error();
    }
} else {
    show_error();
}

require_once 'views/layout/footer.php';
```

```
tienda-php/views/layout/header.php

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,  initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

    <title>PROYECTO TIENDA</title>

    <!--short icon!-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">

    <!--CSS !-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url?>./assets/css/styles.css">

    <!--font awesome!-->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/46fc319774.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="contenedor-general">

        <!-- CABECERA header -->
        <header class="header" id="cabecera">

            <!-- LOGO -->
            <div id="logo" class="logo">
                <a class="titulo" href="#">
                    <i class="fab fa-php"></i> Tienda
                </a>
            </div>


            <!-- MENU -->
            <nav id="menu" class="nav">

                <button class="toggle" aria-label="Abrir menu">
                    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                </button>

                <ul class="nav-menu ">
                    <!--!-->
                    <li class="nav-menu-item">
                        <a href="index.php" class="nav-menu-link nav-link">Inicio</a>
                    </li>
                    <!--!-->


                    <!--!-->
                    <li class="nav-menu-item">
                        <a href="categoria.php?id3" class="nav-menu-link nav-link">Python</a>
                    </li>
                    <!--!-->


                    <!--!-->
                    <li class="nav-menu-item">
                        <a href="categoria.php?id5" class="nav-menu-link nav-link">JS</a>
                    </li>
                    <!--!-->


                    <!--!-->
                    <li class="nav-menu-item">
                        <a href="categoria.php?id7" class="nav-menu-link nav-link">JAVA</a>
                    </li>
                    <!--!-->


                    <!--!-->
                    <li class="nav-menu-item">
                        <a href="categoria.php?id8" class="nav-menu-link nav-link">Php</a>
                    </li>
                    <!--!-->


                    <!--!-->
                    <li class="nav-menu-item">
                        <a href="categoria.php?id10" class="nav-menu-link nav-link">RUBY</a>
                    </li>
                    <!--!-->


                    <!--!-->
                    <li class="nav-menu-item">
                        <a href="categoria.php?id10" class="nav-menu-link nav-link">DATA BASES</a>
                    </li>
                    <!--!-->


                    
                    <!--!-->
                    <li class="nav-menu-item">
                        <a href="categoria.php?id9" class="nav-menu-link nav-link">Sist. operativos</a>
                    </li>
                    <!--!-->





                    <!--!-->
                    <li class="nav-menu-item">
                        <a href="index.php" class="nav-menu-link nav-link">Sobre mi</a>
                    </li>
                    <!--!-->
                    <li class="nav-menu-item">
                        <a href="index.php" class="nav-menu-link nav-link nav-menu-link_active">Contacto</a>
                    </li>
                    <!--!-->
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </header>



        <!-- <div id="contenedor"> -->
```

Comment: El error *Cannot modify header information - headers already sent*, probablemente sea porque está imprimiento HTML antes de llegar a un `header("Location: ...")`. Mira [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/249103/80870) y [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/94066/80870). O también: búsqueda general de [esa pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+header+already+sent)

Comment: Revisa los `echo` que tienes en tu código, seguramente alguno esta enviando algo a la salida antes del header(location) como ya te han dicho, o quizas se intenta mostrar un error que sale antes del header.

Comment: O comenta el header y prueba de nuevo, y mira lo que sale para saber de que se trata

Comment: Hola ya intenten lo que me dijiste no se que mas podria ser

Comment: Pues revisa los php y que ninguno tenga una línea vacia al principio, es decir, todos los PHP implicados deben tener `<?php` justo en la primera linea, y si los cierras al final del archivo con `?>` entonces tambien alli que no haya nada mas, porque sino estas enviando esa linea vacia a la salida antes del header